# pass attribute values using html 5 local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Is there any way to send the value of src attribute (in img tag html) to another webpage using html5  local storage ? I already found a javascript method but just wondering whether there is another easy way using HTML5 local storage

Comment: You need to show your code. What you have tried, in the question or in a fiddle.

Comment: Can't you just throw the value into a cookie? Does it have to be local storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
localStorage.setItem("key","value")
```

you can get it back as :

```
localStorage.getItem("key")
```

assuming your image has an id "img1"

```
var value1 = $("#img1").attr("src");
localStorage.setItem("image_source","value1")
```

and you can retrieve it back to check conditions using:

```
localStorage.getItem("image_source")
```

**using cookies**

either you can set the value server side or you can set it at the present page like this:

```
document.cookie="image_source="+value1;
```